# Grouping aggregate by day

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a simple table `log` in a Postgres database that looks like this (simplified for the example):

```
time::timestamptz
action::varchar

time                          | action
2017-10-16 17:14:49.473903-08 | 'some action'
2017-10-16 17:14:49.473903-08 | 'some other action'
2017-10-17 17:14:49.473903-08 | 'some action'
//etc.
```

There are a variety of actions. I want to query this table to get one row per day with a column that contains an array of the counts of each action. This is the result I want:

```
day            actions
'2017-10-08' | [{"action":"some action", "count":10}, 
             |  {"action":"some other action", "count":20}}]
'2017-10-09' | [{"action":"some action", "count":15}, 
             |  {"action":"some other action", "count":18}}]
```

I can almost get there with this:

```
SELECT day, json_agg(act) as actions
FROM (
    SELECT action, time::date as day,  COUNT(*)
    FROM log_hits
    GROUP BY (action, day)
) act
GROUP BY day
```

This, of course, results in the date occurring in each the object in the actions array…

```
day           actions
'2017-10-08' | [{"action":"some action", day:"2017-10-08", "count":10}, 
             |  {"action":"some other action",  day:"2017-10-08", "count":20}}]
```

…which is redundant (and possible inefficient). What is the correct way to get the results grouped by day, with the day only occurring in its own column and the actions aggregate only being for that day?

Comment: What postgres version?

Comment: @Mihai I'm running 9.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `jsonb_build_object():`

```
WITH log_hits (time, action) AS (
VALUES
    ('2017-10-16 17:14:49.473903-08'::timestamptz, 'some action'),
    ('2017-10-16 17:14:49.473903-08', 'some other action'),
    ('2017-10-17 17:14:49.473903-08', 'some action')
)

SELECT 
    day, 
    json_agg(jsonb_build_object('action', action, 'count', count)) as actions
FROM (
    SELECT action, time::date as day, COUNT(*)
    FROM log_hits
    GROUP BY (action, day)
) act
GROUP BY day;

    day     |                                       actions                                        
------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2017-10-17 | [{"count": 1, "action": "some action"}, {"count": 1, "action": "some other action"}]
 2017-10-18 | [{"count": 1, "action": "some action"}]
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first convert the row into a jsonb then remove the `day` key

```
SELECT day, json_agg(row_to_jsonb(act) - 'day') as actions
FROM (
    SELECT action, time::date as day,  COUNT(*)
    FROM log_hits
    GROUP BY action, day
) act
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not exactly the result you are asking for*, but posting anyway because somebody may find it more suitable:

```
SELECT day, json_object_agg("action","count") as actions
FROM (
    SELECT action, ts::date as day, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM log_hits
    GROUP BY (action, ts::date) ORDER BY count DESC
) act
GROUP BY day ORDER BY day

|        day |                                        actions |
|------------|------------------------------------------------|
| 2017-10-16 | { "some action" : 2, "some other action" : 1 } |
| 2017-10-17 |                          { "some action" : 1 } |
| 2017-10-18 |                          { "some action" : 1 } |
```